# Re-entering EU via a country other than your Resident Permit Country

Tags: schengen, eu

I have a Hungarian Resident Permit. I'm planning to re-enter the EU (from Asia) via Italy, since the ticket is cheaper than flying to Budapest. I will spend a few days in Rome and then fly to Budapest.

Is this possible? does anyone have any experience entering the EU from outside of it via a country other than your resident permit issued country?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between the EU and the Schengen area. Both Hungary and Italy are Schengen members.

With a residence permit from one Schengen member you can enter the other Schengen states as if you had a short-stay visa, that is you can stay up to 90 out of 180 days, you cannot work there, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I should have worded it entering Schengen zone. I checked in other places and some people have mentioned it's possible too. My only concern is since, I'm coming from outside of the schengen zone, or I know it's quite straight forward to travel around the schengen zone. Thanks again!